# Unity Falling Platform with Return

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code why its Falling Platform with Return

```
public class Falling : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 initialPosition;
    bool platformMovingBack;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (platformMovingBack)
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, initialPosition, 20f * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.y == initialPosition.y)
            platformMovingBack = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name.Equals("Personage_0") && !platformMovingBack)
        {
            Invoke("DropPlatform", 0.5f);
        }
    }

    void DropPlatform()
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        Invoke("GetPlatformBack", 1f);
    }

    void GetPlatformBack()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        platformMovingBack = true;
    }
}
```

After a couple of seconds the platform returns to its original position, but then it gets deleted and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: I assume with disappears you don't mean deleted, right? when you look in the Editor and select the platform, you can see where it is. Is it maybe falling way down below, where you cannot see it?

Comment: No the platform gets deleted i wrote it wrong

Comment: Then the problem has to be somewhere else. At least I can't see any way, how it could get deleted with this script.

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors in your console? Any other scripts on the platform which can cause a delete?

Comment: There are no other scripts on the platform

Comment: @MartijnVerkerke But is there a Script, which uses the Destroy method. Maybe with an collision event

Comment: @SebastianKilb i got a previous script i used, to let the platform fall and then it gets deleted. But that script is inactive right now

Comment: Obviously some script is still calling the destroy function. You say that a collision script is "inactive". Can you try and remove the object containing the "inactive" script from your scene?

Comment: @SebastianKilb found the problem about why it gets deleted. but if i stand on the platform after it has return. it wont fall anymore

Comment: @Immorality did what you asked deleted the previous one and now i returns but wont repeat the script (so if it return it wont fall anymore) thank you btw

Comment: @MartijnVerkerke Vector2.MoveTowards is like Lerp it will never end up in the target position, but will continuously move 0.000...0001 steps closer. This means transform.position.y == initialPosition.y will never be true. What you have to do is, to check if the distance is smaller than 0.1 for example. Vector2.Distance(transform.position, initialPosition)

Answer (score 1):

Your `platformMovingBack` will not be set to `false` in every case. Change this:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (platformMovingBack)
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, initialPosition, 20f * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.y == initialPosition.y)
            platformMovingBack = false;
    }
```

to:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (platformMovingBack)
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, initialPosition, 20f * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - initialPosition.y) < (Time.deltaTime *2.0f)){
            platformMovingBack = false;
            transform.position = initialPosition;
        }
    }
```

for example...

As mentioned from Sebastian Kilb right now in the comments ;)